# Work Information always returns null

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having an issue with retrieving work information of people and it always returns null even if public data available. I use FaceBook.dll and pass below query to FacebookClient.

```
select uid, username, first_name, middle_name, last_name,work 
from user 
where uid in (598632817)
```

But what I got for the work information is null ("work":null). Any idea how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when the information is public, using the API you always must specify a valid access token for getting it.  Otherwise, you can get it from `http://graph.facebook.com/598632817` if it is truly public.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By mistake I hadn't pass the FB Token. Once I pass the correct token, Work information are received.